# sending array from javascript through url in php page but

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

Rooms are an array

```
window.location = "booking_status.php?array="+ JSON.stringify(rooms);
```

sending from javascript to php page
on php page url show full array value which are store in array in page address bar url
like that

> http://localhost/zalawadi/booking_status.php?array=[**{%22id%22:10,%22rate%22:100}**]

I want to prevent this data which show in url `%22id%22:10,%22rate%22:100`

I am decoding on php page any other way to send array data from javascript to php **page**

Comment: Use the POST method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden form and the post method. Then you would use $_POST instead of $_GET.

```
<form action="script.php" onsubmit="this.firstChild.value=JSON.stringify(value);">
    <input type="hidden" value="" />
    <a href="javascript:this.form.submit();">Link text</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to send data to another page without showing them in the url is to use POST.

Basically, you can put your data into an invisible form input :

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="booking_status.php">
    <input name="array" id="array" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
<a href="" onclick="sendForm(); return false;">Send</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendForm(){
        document.getElementById('array').value = JSON.stringify(rooms);
        document.getElementById('form').submit(); //fixed syntax
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the grey "check" icon below the vote count. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `POST` the data instead then?

For example, with `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "booking_status.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(rooms),
  success: // add success function here!
});
```

The advantage is you're not passing some horrific URL. As an added bonus, this example is also asynchronous, so the user doesn't see any refresh in their browser.

**Non-Framework Version**

If you don't wish to use `jQuery`, you can do this with pure Javascript, using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, like so:

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var param = JSON.stringify(rooms);

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);


http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    // Request has gone well. Add something here.
    }
}
http.send(param);
```

Comment: Do you see a jQuery tag anywhere in this question?

Comment: Oh hello captain hostile. I thought it would be a suggestion.

Comment: i don;t know much about this http.onreadystagechange i  mostly use jquery post method

Answer (score 0):

You can use a POST request, however this would require generating and submitting a form:

```
// assuming `rooms` already defined
var frm = document.createElement('form'), inp = document.createElement('input');
frm.action = "booking_status.php";
frm.method = "post";
inp.type = "hidden";
inp.name = "array";
inp.value = JSON.stringify(rooms);
frm.appendChild(inp);
document.body.appendChild(frm);
frm.submit();
```